# django rest post return 405 error code

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using django with rest framework and I try to test POST on existing object but I keep getting 405. my ViewSet looks like this:

```
class Agents(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializer.AgentSerializer
    model = serializer_class.Meta.model
    ....
```

and in the urls:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'rest/agents', api_views.Agents, "Agent")
...
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

I call the post request from within APITestCase class (rest testing), my post request looks like this:

```
response = self.client.post(url, {'available': True, 'online':True}, format='json')
```

and printing url shows "/chat/rest/agents/1910_1567/", while 1910_1567 is the valid id of an existing agent (I create the agent during the setup and use its id).

I've seen other questions about rest post getting 405, but all the solutions there were url-related and in my case the url is correct. I even ran the setup outside the test and accessed the url via browser to get the object and the object indeed exist. but when I try to post to it - 405.

any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: PS I think its pretty obvious but when I override the update() function and add print that print is never called, eg I'm getting 405 not from the implementation of update but before that. really looks like url-related but I validated the url and its ok :/

Comment: Is the trailing slash supposed to be there? What if you set `router = SimpleRouter(trailing_slash=False)`?

Comment: @Railslide post urls usually end with trailing slash, but I did try what you suggested and got the same result.

Comment: What if you curl to it?

Comment: @Railslide I don't understand - what do you mean by "curl to it"? thanks :)

Comment: to try to reach the url via curl instead of via browser

Comment: @Railslide ah I see. instead of curl I added "response = self.client.get(url, {}, format='json')" one line above the post and it return 200.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80646/discussion-between-railslide-and-ness).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POST are supposed to be for creation purpose. If you want to update with a ViewSet you'll need to PUT or PATCH (partial update) instead.

Edit:
For more about this, here's some explanation on the HTTP methods used for REST API:
http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html

This is also described in the DRF documentation at:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter

Comment: are you sure about this? can you please add link to doc reference? thanks :)

Comment: Sure, this is described in the router section:http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter

Comment: Indeed you are right. I'm used to rest apis that accept "post" as a way to update existing objects, I guess django-rest is more strict about it... thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Most probably your url is somehow matching with some different url's regex, and the request is being dispatched to some other view which disallows post request. Could you mention others urls in your urls.py? Infact you can verify this by adding pdb(debugger) in dispatch method of your view. If you made it to the pdb, then you can assume I was wrong.

If that is not the case, then you can evaluate the issue from dispatch method with debugger. Just in case you have any doubt about how to do that -

```
class Agents(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     serializer_class = serializer.AgentSerializer
     model = serializer_class.Meta.model

     def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
         import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
         return super(Agents, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Solution Found:-**

You are passing id in url, so this request would be routed to detail view and detail view only allow GET, PUT, DELETE operations on resource since resource already exists. So to create resource, don't provide the id. Otherwise use PUT request and provide support for creation in PUT.

Comment: thanks hspandher, but that's not the problem. the namespace "/chat/rest" is unique for this object api, and just to make sure I added get() call to the same url one line above and it works and return the agent object properly. (I rather not post the urls because its kind of long and I don't want to add "noise" to the question)

Comment: thank you for the debugging example! I debugged the dispatch and found out that the ViewSet object don't have a post method! it returns 405 due to this line: handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed), where request.method is indeed post. so why don't I have post in my ViewSet if I used viewsets.ModelViewSet? any ideas how it makes sense? thanks! :)

Comment: Is it happening only in test or in browser too??

Comment: in browser too, using rest framework default view I'm getting ""detail": "Method \"POST\" not allowed."". EDIT: I see "Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, HEAD, OPTIONS" in the header data, and as soon as I add post() method to my ViewSet object and refresh, "POST" is added to the allow list. it make sense, but the post() should be created automatically for ModelViewSet, isn't it?